# Optimizing Fourier Series Fitting Function Matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, curve-fitting, continuous-fourier

I am trying to iterate through a set of samples that seems to show periodic changes. I need continuously apply the fit function to get the fourier series coefficients, the regression has to be n samples in the past (in my case, around 30). The problem is, my code is extremely slow! It will take like 1 hour to do this for a set of 50,000 samples. Is there any way to optimize this? What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
function[coefnames,coef] = fourier_regression(vect_waves,n)        

    j = 1;
    coef = zeros(length(vect_waves)-n,10);

    for i=n+1:length(vect_waves)

        take_fourier = vect_waves(i-n+1:i);
        x = 1:n;
        f = fit(x,take_fourier,'fourier4');
        current_coef = coeffvalues(f);
        coef(j,1:length(current_coef)) = current_coef;
        j = j + 1;



    end
    coefnames = coeffnames(f);

end
```

When I call `[coefnames,coef] = fourier_regression(VECTOR,30);` This takes forever to compute. Is there any way to fix it? What's wrong with my code?

Note: I have a intel i7 5500 U cpu, 16GB RAM, and using Matlab 2015a.

Comment: Where does the `coeffnames` come from? You do not define that one before you call it in your penultimate line. I suggest you also state what is contained within `vect_waves`, i.e. what sort of numbers and possibly post the first 10 or so lines so we can try the code ourselves. Also please post what kind of system you are on: CPU, RAM, OS, MATLAB version, that way we can see whether it is hardware/software related.

Comment: Coeffnames comes from "fit", it is given automatically by Matlab when you call "fit" using Fourier. vect_waves is pretty much a vector with 500k samples containing a signal, that's all (a bunch of numbers between [-1,1]). I posted more info of my hardware on the post.

Comment: So basically that's ALL the code I have.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not familiar with your application, I am not sure whether it is possible to vectorize the code to improve performance. However, I have a couple of other tips.

One thing you should consider is [preallocation of arrays](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html). In this case, you should preallocate at least the array `coef` since I believe you do know its size before starting the loop.

Another thing I suggest is to [profile your code](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html). This will provide information on what parts of your code are consuming the most time, helping you focus your effort on improving those parts' performance.

Comment: I have tried preallocating the arrays but on this case, it did not help at all. I am not sure if it would be possible to vectorize my code, since I need to use the fit function N times and not just one time. I am guessing the "fit" function is just slow, so I might consider writing my own function for getting the fourier series coefficients, but just wanted to make sure if there was anything else I could do instead...